# Set values before $args array to get metabox date as converted to new format

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$args = array( 
              'meta_key' => $new_date_format,
              'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'posts_per_page' => 4,
              );

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );                      


if( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

$timestamp = strtotime(vp_metabox('event_date.date_event'));
$new_date_format = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

I would like to sort my date today to latest or asc. I have this little problem.. "$new_date_format" only works inside my loop in which I have to use it outside to be able to use it as the 'meta_key'. How do i make it work outside loop and still be able to get the value and use it for 'meta_key'?
[image]

Comment: You're attempting to use the `$new_date_format` before it's been instantiated. Also, Is the `meta_key` you're trying to use an individual date or is it a column name more like `event_date`? Either way the `$new_date_format` is always going to be blank if it hasn't yet been created.

Comment: Exactly. I want it to initialized before the loop starts but metabox values will only work inside the loop.

Comment: is the `meta_key` titled as a `date('Y-m-d')` or is titled as something like `date_event`? if so you do not need to initialize it first you need to set the `meta_key => "column name"`

Comment: @Rhetorical The `meta_key` before converted to `('Y-m-d')` is shown as "March 22, 2018"

Comment: the `meta_key` is `event_date`, the name of the column you're looking for not the meta_value which is what you have circled. I've posted a hopefully better answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and updated photo of your database table you should be using `event_date` as the `meta_key`. Right now you're attempting to get the `meta_key` with the `meta_value`

```
$args = array( 
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
 );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );                      

if( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    $timestamp = strtotime(vp_metabox('event_date.date_event'));
    $new_date_format = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Helpful. I did `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` and converted to new date format inside loop. Currently working now.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how do i show 'next month events' and 'this week events'?

Comment: You could use the wp_meta_query functionality to grab the information for each post that has multiple meta_values for the same meta_key. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: Looking at your data in the column for `meta_value` it looks like it's a JSON object and the `wp_meta_query` would be only for data types like `datetime`. You would need to write a loop of some sort to grab all of the values and then loop through them to order them.